# batch file to open txt replace text save and close

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text, replace

I understand that this community is for helping people and I'm not one hundred percent how to ask for someone to do a commissioned job or w/e but I'd like a series of batch files for changing certain numbers to a particular number per batch file.

```
echo off
if exist %application.yml del %application.yml
for /F "delims=" %%l in (%1) do (
    set "line=%%l"
    set "line=%line:specific text=another word%"
    echo/%line%>> %application.yml)'
```

How would I set this to replace an array of numbers to the set number, I'm sorry I'm a complete idiot with this.

File itself `application.yml`

```
product: 
# Cntrl alt 1 Mini, 2 m16, 3 scar, 4 m4169, 5 akm, 6 ump,7 sks
discordUsername: 
discordPassword: 
maxCPUsUsage: 4
shutdownKey: 0x7B
reloadConfigKey: 0x79

screenResolutionX: 1920
screenResolutionY: 1080

playerEsp: true
playerEspColor: 0xFF00FF
playerEspPointSize: 1

radarEsp: true
radarEspColor: 0x0000FF
radarEspPointSize: 2

vehicleEsp: true
vehicleEspColor: 0xff0000
vehicleEspPointSize: 1
vehicleEspHotkey: 0x2D

lootEsp: true
lootEspColor: 0x00FF00
lootAirdropEspColor: 0xffffff
lootEspPointSize: 1
lootEspHotkey: 0x24

redrawTime: 0
reloadDataTime: 2000

aimEnabled: true
aimKey: 0x39
aimFOV: 95
aimFrequency: 6
aimPrecision: 1
aimSpeed: 1
bulletSpeed: 990
aimHitbox: 0

# Key list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx
```

So essentially the number I wish to replace is the bullet speed and it could be multiple numbers from previous changes ect, for example

```
990
870
400
```

and if it is any of these instances I wish to replace it with

```
900
```

and so on and so forth.

So it searches for any of the possible numbers and changes it to the specified number and save the file under the same file name.

Thanks in advance for any help if I'm being completely honest in the example I dont even know what to change to make it simply replace one number to the other never mind multiple instance searches :)

Once again ty for any advice or help.

Comment: This site isn't the right place for requesting commisioning a programmer, however if you were to post a sample of the input file, `%1` with it's precise layout and an indication of its size, you may be lucky enough to get a response which could save you having to commision somebody. BTW, do not post code and file information into the comment section, add it to your original post using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46378073/edit) facility.

Comment: I have edited your post again to hopefully format your newly added `.yml` file correctly, if it is now wrong please let me know! Are you wanting to only replace the exact value matching `990` anywhere in that file or is your intention only to replace matching values belonging only to `bulletSpeed` or something else.

Comment: You are wonderful, thank you for your help :)

Comment: basically im looking to make a number of batch files to edit that (the bullet speed) or any of the other bullet speeds to certain batch files so that i can assign them to macro keys on the keyboard for on the fly bullet speed changes. i can do the leg work im just after the basic code really :)

Comment: but yes just the bullet speed. tho the numbers for each of the bullet speeds should co relate to anything else within the .yml

Comment: The reason I asked about the `bulletSpeed` thing is because for example your `400` could also be found in `reloadDataTime` and is also a likely string to find within your hex values too. BTW, if you have no objections to powershell solutions, which may improve your options you should add the powershell tag as an edit to your question too!

Comment: you are completely right i can change the reload data time to something obscure to prevent that issue tho, its not essential to being that number per-say. i appreciate the idea and shall add the tag :) thanks again for all your support :)

Comment: There's no need to change that at all, any script can ensure that only the `bulletSpeed` data value is replaced, if that is what you need.

Comment: wonderful, im off to bed myself but ill do a bunch of reading tomorrow and perhaps be able to devise an answer myself :) thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

The following *commented* `.bat` script should do the job, although empty lines are not copied to output file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem redirect all output to a brand new file
>application.yml (
  rem parse a file (supplied file name %1 must not be equal to "application.yml")   
  for /F "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%~1") do (
      rem parse each line
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%L in ("%%~l") do (
          if /I "%%~L"=="bulletSpeed" (
              rem modified line
              echo(%%L: 900
          ) else (
              rem original line 
              echo(%%l
          )
      )
  )
)
```

BTW, in the *original script*, you would need [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to make proper reference to variables (re)defined within a parenthesised code block (like a `FOR` loop body), e.g. as follows:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist application.yml del application.yml
for /F "delims=" %%l in (%1) do (
    set "line=%%l"
    set "line=!line:specific text=another word!"
    echo/!line!>>application.yml
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~L` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>>`, `>` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are ideal to do this sort of editing.
Aside from findstr's limited capabilities batch is lacking RE support.

This wrapped powershell one liner will do the job either on cmd line or in a batch-file.

```
powershell -NoP -C "(gc application.yml) -Replace '(?<=bulletSpeed: )\d+','900'|sc application.yml"
```

It uses a [lookbehind assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to replace any number following `bulletSpeed:` with 900.

To limit the replacement to one of previous 990, 870, 400 use this:

```
powershell -NoP -C "(gc application.yml) -Replace '(?<=bulletSpeed: )(990|870|400)','900'|sc application.yml"
```